# Qt Creator. Why do I get an error about glut when compiling release version, but not debug?

Tags: c++, qt, build, release, glut

I'm rather new to Qt and I'm having trouble building a stand alone executable for my application.
It has OpenGL widgets and I've used glut32 library.
The thing is that I've been buiding it fine in debug mode, but following the steps given here:

[How to create executable file for a Qt Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312725/how-to-create-executable-file-for-a-qt-application)

It gives an error when buiding it in release mode:

" Undifined reference to ___glutInitWithExit "

It's the very same code. I don't understand why it is having trouble under release.

I thank in advance any tips to help me buid a standalone executable.

Comment: It means that you need to link GLUT library. I don't know Qt Creator but for example in Visual Studio there's separate linker configurations for Debug and Release versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static single executables you will first need a commercial license for QT. This being said you can change the mkspecs in $QTDIR\mkspecs\$COMPILERVERSION\qmake.conf to use static linking. For example win32-msvc2008 (2008 Visual Studio Compiler) set CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS from

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MD
```

to

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MT
```

(MD => MT, MDd => MTd). Furthormore you will static libs of QT and GLUT. These typically end in .lib (not .dll). You probably will need to compile QT from Source for getting static-compatible libraries. When compiling QT remember to compile with opengl support. There is a good documentation at http://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Static_Qt_For_Windows_With_Gcc_German for gcc, and you can also find examples for MSVC.

After these prerequisites are met you still need to set in your Application-pro-file

```
CONFIG += static
```

and include your libraries with:

```
LIBS += -Lpath/to/glutlib -lglut
```