# mingwm10.dll missing in the bin folder

Tags: qt

I was trying to create a exe file of my Qt project.

I found this post: [How to create executable file for a Qt Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312725/how-to-create-executable-file-for-a-qt-application)
and realised that i dont have a mingwm10.dll file in that directory.

Are there any other ways of creating a exe file or any other location where mingwm10.dll might be located?

I am using qt 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mingwm10.dll` is a runtime file for the MinGW.org toolchain. Qt moved towards a MinGW-w64-based toolchain (which is essentially an expanded and newer implementation of the Win32 headers and import libraries), which doesn't have this runtime dependency. Ignore it, you don't need it. You might need the libgcc and libstdc++ DLLs though, but that's the same with any (non-statically built) toolchain.

Note you can use the windeployqt utility to automatically copy over all runtime depencies of an executable. You can enable it by adding `windeployqt` to `CONFIG` if you're using qmake, or you could just run it yourself:

```
windeployqt my_app.exe
```

This command will copy all DLLs (including the Qt platform plugins etc.) so that the application can be run by e.g. double-clicking, instead of only in the specific environment of an IDE.

Comment: Just a note: the deploy tool doesn't work that great. There are often many libraries that you have to copy manually afterwards that the tool simply doesn't seem to want to copy even if the dependencies have been given as arguments to the call of the tool.