# Build (compile) a basic standalone .exe application using Qt-creator on Windows 8

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have installed Qt-5.7 on windows 8 because I couldn't build my released .exe from Linux (my favorite) in order to be used on Windows OS even after searching a lot on internet (Where there have to be cross-compilation...). After the installation, I just want to make sure that I can build/run a first application (one of the examples provided by default by Qt-creator "filesystembrows") and I have follow [the official guide](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html) in order to build Qt as shared libraries, but the issue is that when I type the first command line I get: `'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command'` Also it still show the same message even though a update the variable environment of the system with `C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\bin` which one is the default path set-up when installing Qt on windows. Any help just to make a stand alone .exe for Windows (as shared libraries ) please

Comment: I am trying to understand the situation. So you want a standalone .exe with the libraries dynamically linked? is that correct? If so, just copy the required dll's and place them into a folder with the .exe

Comment: yes this is what I want

Comment: okay, try this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312725/how-to-create-executable-file-for-a-qt-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not build your project by using qtcreator ?

Did you test your build environnement by making a test application with qtcreator ?

P.S.: If you want, I can explain how to build application using Visual Studio as a compiler and QtCreator as an IDE.

Comment: What do you mean ? Do you want some explanations about how use Visual Studio and QtCreator ? Or do you want to make a test application with qtcreator ?

Answer (score 0):

`nmake` is a build tool provided with Visual Studio and with Windows SDK. You don't have it, apparently.

It seems you're using a mingw build of Qt; it comes with a bundled copy of mingw. There, the build tool is simply called `make`.