# Need UPDATED version of how to make qt do static compiles on windows

Tags: qt, build, static

I just made a program in QT, I would like to distribute it but I want a static build, not one that I need to ship all the libraries with it. I have been looking everywhere for a guide on it and they all describe things that I do not have. If someone could please help me out,  I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011197/qt-static-linking-and-deployment) is for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my rough notes. I did this a few days ago.

Downloaded Mingw32
http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download?source=files

And I choose to add the msys package too. this is a cmd msys.bat file that sets up the env for you.
I installed the above to c:\MinGW and double clicked the C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\msys.bat

Downloaded the QT Source
http://releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.2.zip

I unzipped the above to c:\qt-src-4.8.2

using the msys command line I changed directory to the above directory and typed this:

configure.exe -static -platform win32-g++ -release -exceptions

this took about 15 minutes

Then I typed:

mingw32-make sub-src

This took hours.

Installing QT Creator,
Downloaded from:
Installed to : C:\qtcreator-2.5.0
Run qtcreator
Tools > Options QT Versions. Add > Browse to qmake.exe in the c:\qt-src-4.8.2
Tool Chain > Add MinGW > Browse to the g++.exe

Modify the makespecs
Open C:\qt-src-4.8.2\mkspecs\win32-g++\qmake.conf
add QMAKE_LFLAGS = -static -static-libgcc
Then to test the static build, open the .pro file
CONFIG += static

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother doing static compilation with Qt. You are going to spend hours on it and you're not even sure to succeed. Use Qt as it's meant to be used - with separate DLLs.