# Create a Application in QT Creator in windows

Tags: windows, qt, qt4, cross-platform

Currently working on an application using QT in Windows.In Qt i am facing static linking deployment in windows. How to proceed on it?

How to statically link the Qt libraries, so that we can deploy an independent application.

Note: The application has to be runned in Linux, MACOS, Windows, how to cross compile it.Please give me the guidelines also.

Comment: You do know that static linking needs Qt commercial license or open-source project with providing source code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt static linking and deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011197/qt-static-linking-and-deployment)