# Why do I have put linker flags for X libraries in my Makefile when integrating static libQtGui and libQtCore

Tags: qt, makefile, shared-libraries, static-libraries, linker-errors

When I make static libraries of Qt  (libQtCore.a and libQtGui.a) using following steps

```
1) cd to path for qt-x11-commercial-src-4.3.3
2) setenv PATH /pathto-qt-x11-commercial-src-4.3.3/bin:$PATH
3) gmake confclean
4) ./configure -release -static -largefile -qt3support -qt-libpng                       -qt-libmng -qt-libtiff -qt-libjpeg -glib -platform linux-g++-64 -confirm-license -no-openssl -no-qdbus -prefix ./static_new -prefix-install -opengl -sm             -L/usr/lib64  -lSM -lICE -xshape -lX11 -xinerama -lXinerama -xcursor -lXcursor -xfixes -lXfixes -xrandr -lXrandr -xrender -lXrender -fontconfig -lfontconfig -tablet -lXi -xkb -glib -lglib-2.0 -lXext 
5) gmake 
6 gmake install
```

then I have to explicitly put following lines in my makefile to link  X libraries in my final executable

```
SLIBS      += SM ICE Xi Xrender Xfixes Xrandr Xcursor Xinerama freetype Xext z gthread-2.0  glib-2.0 QtGui QtCore fontconfig
```

otherwise I get undefined reference for symbols in above  X libraries.

But when I make shared libraries of libQtGui.so and libQtCore.so using following steps

```
1) cd to path for qt-x11-commercial-src-4.3.3
2) setenv PATH /pathto-qt-x11-commercial-src-4.3.3/bin:$PATH
3) gmake confclean
4) configure -release -shared -largefile -qt3support -qt-libpng -qt-libmng\
-qt-libtiff -qt-libjpeg -glib -platform linux-g++-64 -confirm-license -no-openssl -no-qdbus -prefix ./static_new -prefix-install -opengl -sm -L/usr/lib64 -lSM -lICE -xshape -lX11 -xinerama -lXinerama \
-xcursor -lXcursor -xfixes -lXfixes -xrandr -lXrandr -xrender -lXrender \
 -fontconfig -lfontconfig -tablet -lXi -xkb -glib -lglib-2.0 -lXext -lz \
  -lgthread-2.0
5 gmake 
6 gmake install
```

then I only have to put following lines in my makefile

```
SLIBS      += QtGui QtCore
```

I do not have to put code in my makefile to link X libraries in the final executable

My question in why do have explicitly link  X libraries while integrating static libraries  libQtGui.a and libQtCore.a in my final executable

Comment: I hope [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011197/qt-static-linking-and-deployment) helps you.