# Qt cannot create standalone exe

Tags: c++, qt, mingw, qt-creator, mingw32

I have seen a lot of topics, questions and solutions online but still I cannot fix this issue. I have an exe which is 1.7 KB size but when I move it to another computer and I try to open it there is the typical error. I use QtCreator **4.4.0**.

[image]

When I try to add `Qt5Core.dll`, `Qt5Gui.dll` and `QtWidgets.dll` then I get the error

> Unable to find the entry point

What to do now?

---

- I have executed `windeployqt` but I have a 600 MB of dlls!! There are `Qt5Core.dll` and `Qt5Cored.dll` among these
- I have tested the solution I have found online which says "use static linking". Well I have added "`CONFIG += static`" then in the IDE I give a Project > Build and Project > Run qmake.

Still the errors. I have been struggling with this since yesterday. So what do I have to do? I need to have a single executable or if it's not possible at least an exe with some dlls (but not 600 MB of dlls).

Comment: Are you sure to not mixing the Qt version and or compiler when build and use `windeployqt`?

Comment: I am new to Qt, I'm not sure...

Comment: OK! Due to size of the dlls gave by `windeployqt` i'm guess that you are in debug mode, please look at the Qt Creator in the box at left side and above the compile (play) button and tell us if it's true!

Comment: Yes it's debug! I've turned it into Release, then Clean All and now I've made Build All. I'll test now and see how it goes!

Comment: We're waiting for your reply! ;)

Comment: @AntonioDias it works now! I had to put it into release mode. By the way I had to add a lot of dlls like QtGui.dll, QtCore.dll, libwinpthread, libstdc++ and libstd_gcc!

Comment: Is it possible to statically link them to the exe? so I have only the exe (the standalone file). Thank you very much btw antonio!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011197/qt-static-linking-and-deployment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:  Due to size of the dlls gave by `windeployqt` i guess that you are in Debug mode, switch to Release mode and yours problems will gone!

For a static linking, you can either search for some instructions to make your own static build of Qt or search for a precompiled binaries if you trust the origin! :)